# Mysql Select users if order is not "ongoing"

Tags: mysql

I want to select those users whose accounts are not in ongoing status.

This table may have multiple rows for each user.

### Order table

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_order` (
 `iOrderID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `iUserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `invoice` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `iTransactionID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `vOrderStatus` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ongoing, expired, free etc.',
);
```

### Description

We can have multiple entries for users. At a time, only one status will be ongoing.

---

**Order ID** | **User ID** | **Invoice** | **Transaction ID** | **Order Status**

---

```
 5             1            INV5             T123333            Ongoing
 4             1            INV4             T123333            expired
 3             2            INV3             T123333            expired
 2             3            INV2             T123333            expired
 1             4            INV1             T123333            expired
```

### Output Should be

---

```
 3             2            INV3             T123333            expired
 2             3            INV2             T123333            expired
 1             4            INV1             T123333            expired
```

Comment: Is it for sql-server? If this question is for mysql then remove tag of sql-server

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_order o
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_order
                 WHERE UserID = o.UserID
                 AND OrderStatus = 'Ongoing');
```

Comment: this query is taking too much time.